# Adobe Air - App upload error - Invalid Executable Size

Tags: ios, build, air, adobe, arm64

We are facing a peculiar problem - We have set the minimum os version to 9.0  through the XML file.

Attaching the xml file's relevant lines

```
-<InfoAdditions>
-<![CDATA[
  <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
  <true/>
  <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
  <array>
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
  </array>
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Access to photo library is required to save images.</string>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
    <string>facebook</string>
    <string>twitter</string>
  </array>
  <key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>fbXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  <string>9.0</string>
]]>
</InfoAdditions>
```

This is the error we are getting after apple processes our build

Invalid Executable Size - The size of your app's executable file '/Payload/AppName.app/AppName' is 63 MB bytes for architecture 'arm64', which exceeds the maximum allowed size of 60 MB.

Now its clearly mentioned in this link that ios9 allows upto 400 mb.  -https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev611e0a21f

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev611e0a21f

My guess is that there is some problem in the way we are writing the minimumos version. Because if the minimum ios version is set to 9, then this error should not happen because the above links says that build upto 400 mb is allowed.

Any idea where we are going wrong?

Thanks & Regards,

Nishant

Comment: Could you post the output of `otool -arch arm64 -l '/Payload/AppName.app/AppName' | fgrep -B1 -A3 LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS` ?

Comment: Hi i got this Load command 9
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS
  cmdsize 16
  version 8.0
      sdk 12.1

Comment: It would seem that your app was compiled with `-miphoneos-version-min=8.0` then (claiming iOS 8.0 compatibility) for whatever reason, and that is likely what triggers the 60MB limit.